Problem with edge creases using subdivision surface
I'm trying to create a shape using subdivision surface that has a sharp edge perpendicular to a smooth face. However, I can't seem to achieve this without causing unwanted distortions. This is an example of the sort of shape I want:

And so far i've only been able to achieve the following using subdivision:


Using bevels prior to subdivision causes this, which isn't much better:

I'm wondering how I could get this shape using only subdivision surface (and maybe a bevel modifier), if possible. The sharp edges are eventually going to be beveled either way, so any solutions that use support loops or whatever would work (that would actually be preferable)

Hello could you please share your file? It's not always possible to avoid a real topology work actually

You probably need a 32 vertex cylinder and sometimes you can't succeed with creases and you need to do real topology like for example this solution:

